# how to prevent mapped Redux dispatch in props causing re-renders in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I was wondering how to reduce re-renders due to referential inconsistencies for actions mapped to props.

Comment: You can use `React.memo` to make memoization to your components. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Comment: Are you sure your re-renders are due to redux dispatch props changing? By default react-redux assumes your component is pure and only calls `mapDispatchToProps` if other dependent props have changed: https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#pure-boolean

Comment: Have you tried with shouldComponentUpdate?

Answer (score 0):

Your can make use of the shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle hook and look to nextProps, or make a comparison between this.props and nextProps, and return true or false depending on whether you want a re-render in that particular instance.

```
class YourComponent extends Component {

   //....

   shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
     // Compare property of this.props to nextProps 
     // or look directly to nextProps and return true or false
   }


   //...

}
```